# Getting the minimum value from user input in a while loop

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements, minimum

I am writing a Python program that continuously asks a user for a number from 1 to 100, then once the user inputs the number 0, the program print out the smallest number and largest number provided, as well as the average of all the numbers.

My only problem: I keep getting 0 as the smallest value of the input when I want to exclude 0.

I have already tried doing the following:

```python
count = 0
total = 0
number = 1
smallest = 0
largest = 0

while number != 0:
    number = int(input("Please input a value from 1 to 100: "))
    
    if number < 0 or number > 100:
        print("Why you give me value outside of range :(\n")
        count -= 1
        continue
   
    count += 1
    total = total + number
    
    if number > largest:
        largest = number

if number == 0:
    count -= 1
    average = total / count
    if number < smallest:
        smallest = number
    print("The results are: ")
    print('Smallest: {}'.format(smallest))
    print('Largest: {}'.format(largest))
    print('Average: {}'.format(average))
    print("\nThank you!")
```

Comment: I get the output: `Smallest: 0`. Is there something else wrong with the program?

Comment: The output should exclude 0 @quamrana

Comment: if number (that is 0) < smallest, then smallest = number = 0

Comment: You have to set `smallest` within the while loop and not change it outside of it.

Comment: The output still includes 0 if I place it within the while loop, unfortunately. @JanChristophTerasa

Comment: Ah, yes, and it has to be initialized to a larger value than your expected maximum input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track *both* the largest and the smallest as the numbers are being input.

Also I have checked for the out of range numbers before any processing takes place:

```py
count = 0
total = 0
number = 0
smallest = 101  # starts bigger than any input number
largest = 0     # starts smaller than any input number

while True:
    number = int(input("Please input a value from 1 to 100: "))
    if number == 0:
        break
    
    if number < 0 or number > 100:
        print("Why you give me value outside of range :(\n")
        continue
   
    count += 1
    total = total + number
    
    if number > largest:
        largest = number

    if number < smallest:
        smallest = number

if number == 0:
    average = total / count
    print("The results are: ")
    print('Smallest: {}'.format(smallest))
    print('Largest: {}'.format(largest))
    print('Average: {}'.format(average))
    print("\nThank you!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `smallest = 101` in the beginning, and

```
if number < smallest:
    smallest = number
```

to your `while` block, and remove the same code in the end.

Also, your `count` is off, you should just remove the two decrements `count -= 1` to fix that.

You can also remove the `if number == 0:`, since you already have `while number != 0:` in the `while` condition, so you know it is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version, this time using a list to hold the valid numbers:

```py
numbers = []

while True:
    number = int(input("Please input a value from 1 to 100: "))
    if number == 0:
        break
    
    if number < 0 or number > 100:
        print("Why you give me value outside of range :(\n")
        continue
   
    numbers.append(number)

if numbers:
    average = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
    print("The results are: ")
    print('Smallest: {}'.format(min(numbers)))
    print('Largest: {}'.format(max(numbers)))
    print('Average: {}'.format(average))
    print("\nThank you!")
```